# Possible to setup a {id}/{controller}/{action} route with null {id}?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site that, for business reasons, needs to have a nonstandard routing setup following

```
{id}/{controller}/{action}.
```

Instead of `http://site/Controller/Id`, I need it to route to `http://site/Id/Controller`.  This works fine in 99% of cases, but if no Id is provided an assumed value (let's just call it "0") will be used.

I managed to get the Home controller by specifying defaults, but what's killing me is trying to get `http://site/MyController` to function as if it were really `http://site/0/MyController`.  Every combination I try seems to try to evaluate `{id}` with "MyController" in absense of an actual `{id}`.

This is my RegisterRoutes currently:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Nullable route tokens can only appear at the end of a route definition and for obvious reasons you can have only one nullable route token otherwise the routing engine has no way of disambiguating your routes. The default route should work in 99.99999999% of the cases.

Comment: if your id can be null shouldn't you check your definition? either of the storage(tables & structures) or your route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional segments can only be placed at the end of your route or better **after required ones**. That's why you have to add an additional route definition without `id` segment that also defines its default as `0`.

### `id` is numeric

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultId",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
    );
}
```

As you can see, the first route definition also includes a constraint for the `id` segment which makes a requirement for it to be numeric. That's the trick.

### `id` is alphanumeric but not matching any controller name

In case `id` is not numeric but can be alpha numeric then you will have to take a different approach...

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultId",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" },
        new { controller = @"Home|Admin|Categories|Items" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
    );
}
```

Then you will have to put a constraint on the `controller` segment, because you have a finite number of them. Mind that route definitions have swapped so the id-less one is now the first and the one with the `id` is now second. This should work as long as `id` can never have the same value as controller name.

### `id` can be anything really

But what if `id` can have a value equal to a controller name? Well in that case you will have to define your routing rules a bit more strictly because you will most likely have to omit default values and provide more routes based on number of segments: zero, one, two, three or even more if required.

Comment: What if `id` were alphanumeric of indeterminate length, like a slug? I tried using `@"\[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` but that didn't work